# Is it possible to vertical align listitem marker in a flowdocument?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I want to to align listitem marker to the top, default is alignment to the bottom of the first
block.

My *faulty* code:

```
<Grid>
    <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
        <FlowDocument>
            <List MarkerStyle="Decimal">
                <ListItem>
                    <BlockUIContainer>
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="HotPink" />
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Picture</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </BlockUIContainer>
                    <Paragraph>TextTextTextTextTextTextText</Paragraph>
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </FlowDocument>
    </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
        <List MarkerStyle="Decimal">
            <ListItem>
                <BlockUIContainer/>     
                    <BlockUIContainer>
                        <Grid Margin="0,-10,0,0">
                            <Rectangle Height="100" Fill="HotPink" />
                            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Picture</TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </BlockUIContainer>
                    <Paragraph>TextTextTextTextTextTextText</Paragraph>
             </ListItem>
        </List>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It works but I think that Microsoft should have made it simpler :)

Comment: hey, ensures those developer jobs :)